# Difference between Export "Ant Buildfiles" and PDE Tools -> Create Ant Build File

Tags: eclipse, ant, build, eclipse-plugin

I want to create the Ant build script for my XText plugin. I read through few articles/tutorial for creating Ant script. I came across 2 ways of creating the Ant script automatically:

1. On plug-in project Right click -> Export -> Ant Buildfiles
2. Right click on the MANIFEST.MF or build.properties or feature.xml and PDE Tools -> Create Ant Build File.

Could someone let me the difference between the above 2 ways?

Comment: Not an exact answer, but the (long, twisted, frustrating) thread here http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/156666/ was really informative.  The best part about reading that thread is that you'll find that at least some other people think that the way the build process works is _completely_ non-intuitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Export...>Ant Buildfiles` will generate a build.xml to build your project as a java project.  `PDE Tools > Create Ant Build File` will create an ant file to build your project as a Plug-in Project (using PDE build).

Comment: Does it actually work?  I seem get different results when I use the ant file that's generated, vs just running the commands in Eclipse.

Comment: You mean `File>Export...>Deployable Plug-in` vs running the PDE created ant file using `org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner`?

Comment: I was using yet another method to generate the ant build file: go through the export dialogs (Right-click project > Export > Deployable Features > Options tab >) and check "save as ant script".  The ant script that produces doesn't look anything at all like you get when you choose PDE Tools > Create Ant Build file.