# Creating Ant Build files for Xtext projects

Tags: ant, build, eclipse-plugin, grammar, xtext

I want to generate a build.xml file for my XText projects to create the jars for them. I tried to do it by File -> Export -> Generate Ant Build files. When I try to run this command to produce build.xml, I get a cycle detection saying "There is a build cycle in the source ...." and the cycle is src -> src-gen -> src. Ant buildfile will not compile your source until this is fixed.

I read about creating a file called customBuildCallbacks.xml in the grammar plug-in to resolve the src -> src-gen -> src cyclic dependency issue ([http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/198855](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/198855/)), but not sure how to use it. If I use the customBuildCallbacks.xml then should I be generating Ant script using **File -> Export -> Generate Ant Build files**  or **PDE Tools -> Create Ant Build File**?

What is way out to get rid of src -> src-gen -> src cycle and generate the build.xml for XText projects?

Comment: please add(edit) the relevant parts of the buildfile into the question

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between Export "Ant Buildfiles" and PDE Tools -> Create Ant Build File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306656/difference-between-export-ant-buildfiles-and-pde-tools-create-ant-build-fil)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no cycle since these are just two folders and the resulting classes are intended to live in the same class folder. Seems like the export wizard for ANT is buggy.

Answer (score 2):

You can also watch this screencast:

- http://xtextcasts.org/episodes/12-building-with-ant

It shows, how to write Ant script to build an Xtext project from scratch.